# How do I call a list of numpy functions without a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I'm doing data analysis that involves minimizing the least-square-error between a set of points and a corresponding set of orthogonal functions. In other words, I'm taking a set of y-values and a set of functions, and trying to zero in on the x-value that gets all of the functions closest to their corresponding y-value. Everything is being done in a 'data_set' class. The functions that I'm comparing to are all stored in one list, and I'm using a class method to calculate the total lsq-error for all of them:

```py
self.fits = [np.poly1d(np.polyfit(self.x_data, self.y_data[n],10)) for n in range(self.num_points)]

def error(self, x, y_set):
    arr = [(y_set[n] - self.fits[n](x))**2 for n in range(self.num_points)]
    return np.sum(arr)
```

This was fine when I had significantly more time than data, but now I'm taking thousands of x-values, each with a thousand y-values, and that `for` loop is unacceptably slow. I've been trying to use `np.vectorize`:

```py
#global scope
def func(f,x):
    return f(x)
vfunc = np.vectorize(func, excluded=['x'])
…
…
#within data_set class
    def error(self, x, y_set):
        arr = (y_set - vfunc(self.fits, x))**2
        return np.sum(arr)
```

`func(self.fits[n], x)` works fine as long as `n` is valid, and as far as I can tell from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), `vfunc(self.fits, x)` should be equivalent to

```py
[self.fits[n](x) for n in range(self.num_points)]
```

but instead it throws:

```py
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 10 to array axis with dimension 11
```

10 is the degree of the polynomial fit, and 11 is (by definition) the number of terms in it, but I have no idea why they're showing up here. If I change the fit order, the error message reflects the change. It seems like `np.vectorize` is taking each element of `self.fits` as a list rather than a `np.poly1d` function.

Anyway, if someone could either help me understand `np.vectorize` better, or suggest another way to eliminate that loop, that would be swell.

Comment: `np.vectorize` does not make things faster.  If I recall an earlier SO, its `excluded=['x']` only works if `x` is a keyword argument.  So not only is it slower than plain iteration, it is harder to use correctly.  It's useful only if you are broadcasting one input argument against another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the functions in question all have a very similar structure we can "manually" vectorize once we've extracted the poly coefficients. In fact, the function is then a quite simple one-liner, `eval_many` below:

```
import numpy as np

def poly_vec(list_of_polys):
    O = max(p.order for p in list_of_polys)+1
    C = np.zeros((len(list_of_polys), O))
    for p, c in zip(list_of_polys, C):
        c[len(c)-p.order-1:] = p.coeffs
    return C

def eval_many(x,C):
    return C@np.vander(x,11).T

# make example
list_of_polys = [np.poly1d(v) for v in np.random.random((1000,11))]
x = np.random.random((2000,))

# put all coeffs in one master matrix
C = poly_vec(list_of_polys)

# test
assert np.allclose(eval_many(x,C), [p(x) for p in list_of_polys])

from timeit import timeit

print('vectorized', timeit(lambda: eval_many(x,C), number=100)*10)
print('loopy     ', timeit(lambda: [p(x) for p in list_of_polys], number=10)*100)
```

Sample run:

```
vectorized 6.817315469961613
loopy      56.35076989419758
```